# Create index for contiguous runs of values

Tags: r, sequence

I have a vector:

```
test <-c(1,1,0,2,2,3,4,1,1,0)  
test  
# [1] 1 1 0 2 2 3 4 1 1 0
```

I want to construct an grouping variable which indicates when values change:

```
# [1] 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 7
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use run length encoding (`rle`), `seq_along`  and `rep`

```
r <- rle(test)

changes <- rep(seq_along(r$lengths), r$lengths)
changes
## [1] 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 7
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative option, which will admittedly only work for numeric data.

```
test <-c(1,1,0,2,2,3,4,1,1,0)  
cumsum(c(1L, diff(test) != 0))
# [1] 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 7
```

And a convoluted variation that will work for any data types:

```
head(cumsum(c(TRUE, c(tail(test, -1), NA) != test)), -1)
# [1] 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 7
```